Kafka starves a partition when another partition has a lot of lag
I have topic1 with 3 partitions and 150k messages of lag and topic2 with 3 partitions and 1 message of lag.
A single consumer and consumer group that covers both topics.
All 6 partitions are assigned to the consumer when I start the consumer.  The consumer consumes the single message from topic2 and then consumes messages from topic1.
If I send a new message to topic2, it doesn't get consumed.
Restarting the consumer will get it to consume the new message but additional new messages after that have the same issue.
I have tried changing maxPollRecords and tried different assigners.

Consumer polling is not guaranteed to be evenly distributed. Why not start 6 consumers?
